# How to find what jquery plugin and css page affect certain element or container in HTML page?

Tags: jquery, plugins, find, element, effect

I need to copy some nice jquery effects(for example a photo album) from one webpage to another website. In my case there are plenty of jquery plugin and css pages linked to that page. Is there any way to find what jquery page or function and css parts are affecting that element or section of the page that create those effects?

Answer (score 1):

You can find great information on what is going on inside the browser by using Google Chrome and Chrome DevTools.

[Here is a link to more information:](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

You can watch styling change in real-time and know which css page is making the change.  You can set break points in javascript / jquery for debugging (or identifying which script is doing what).  There are a lot of tools...